# How would you add captions to these images?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

See: https://jsfiddle.net/6oxt5nfe/

For each slide, I want the image caption to appear at the bottom of the polaroid. What should I do?

I tried putting a  with each img in the HTML, but it would only affect 1 slide and not the rest.

```
Example: .caption {
top 10%
position: absolute
;

<img src=x><div id=caption>this is the caption</div></img>
```

Ideas?

Comment: where is the caption in the fiddle?

Comment: Updated the fiddle. See .caption in CSS. thanks!

Comment: You are missing closing tag for `image-container`

Comment: Each image should be wrapped in a div that has the stylings to make it look like a Polaroid. Then you can just add another div beneath the image in the wrapper to contain the caption:  `<div class='ImageWrapper'><img /><caption /></div>`

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue, you need to add a larger wrapper around the image and the caption together, then you can separate the img and another div for the caption inside of the larger wrapper (alternatively you could also just use a `<p>` tag if you wanted but I prefer to use divs)

Also note that once you make a wrapper like this, you don't need to make your border-width of *.slider* so big (because it will only add on more empty whitespace at the bottom below your caption), so I changed it to 10px.

I made an example for you that I think solves your issue, and I tried to make it as close to your code as possible.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6oxt5nfe/3/

Comment: You are so great! That is perfect. 10 cakes for you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see if there might be a straightforward javascript solution to your question.

Here's what I came up with:

**CSS:**

```
.caption {
position: relative;
top: -65px;
padding: 6px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 36px;
height: 36px;
color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="caption"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var captions = ['Caption 1','Caption 2','Caption 3','Caption 4'];
var imageCaption = document.getElementsByClassName('caption')[0];
imageCaption.innerHTML = captions[0];
var photos = captions.length;
var n = 1;

setInterval(function(){
        imageCaption.innerHTML = captions[n];
        if (n === (photos - 1)) {n = 0;} else {n++;}
        },4000);
```

**Putting it all together:**

```js
var captions = ['Caption 1','Caption 2','Caption 3','Caption 4'];
var imageCaption = document.getElementsByClassName('caption')[0];
imageCaption.innerHTML = captions[0];
var photos = captions.length;
var n = 1;

setInterval(function(){
  imageCaption.innerHTML = captions[n];
  if (n === (photos - 1)) {n = 0;} else {n++;}
  },4000);
```

```css
.slider {
display:block;
position:relative;
margin: 50px auto;
width:100%;
max-width:400px;
max-height:600px;
overflow:hidden;
border: 11px solid #d3d3d3;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 25px solid #ffffff;
border-bottom-width: 80px;
transition: 3s box-shadow ease-in;
box-shadow: 0 0 200px 200px rgba(29, 25, 4, 1) inset, 0 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.image-container {
position:relative;
left:0;
-webkit-transition:left 0.3s;
-moz-transition:left 0.3s;
-ms-transition:left 0.3s;
transition:left 0.3s;
animation: slider 16s infinite;
}

.image-container img{
display:block;
float:left;
}

.four-images {
width:400%;
}

.four-images img {
width:25%;
}

@keyframes slider {
20%{left: 0%;}
25%,45%{left:-100%;}
50%,70%{left:-200%;}
75%,95%{left:-300%;}
}

.caption {
position: relative;
top: -65px;
padding: 6px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 36px;
height: 36px;
color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
<div class="image-container four-images">
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/risemedialibrary-f114ad26-949d-44b4-87e9-8528afc76ce4/imageslider/12.jpg">
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/risemedialibrary-f114ad26-949d-44b4-87e9-8528afc76ce4/imageslider/2.jpg">
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/risemedialibrary-f114ad26-949d-44b4-87e9-8528afc76ce4/imageslider/3.jpg">
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/risemedialibrary-f114ad26-949d-44b4-87e9-8528afc76ce4/imageslider/8.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="caption"></div>
```